# Cassandra 1.2 - Save output.log in another location

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am using datastax cassandra 1.2. 
The output.log file is getting saved at the location /var/log/cassandra/output.log

How do i change the folder location for the output.log.

I have been successful in changing the system.log folder location via the:
/etc/cassandra/log4j-server.properties

Please help. Thanks
Jaskaran

Comment: Why on earth will you use cassandra 1.2 in 2016, latest apache cassandra version is 3.4. And latest datastax enterprise cassandra is 2.1

Comment: Hi Abhishek, we are in process of testing with datastax 2.1 as well.  Then we will migrate to this version. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra daemon uses [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html), this will pipe all the standard/error out to a file specified in `-outfile` (errout to &1 sends to same). This in the Cassandra Debian package is configured in the init script: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.2/debian/init#L141